# How to make Boxes collapsed by default in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a front end developer. And I have very low knowledge on Bootstrap. Basically I have a page which goes like this:

```
<section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Orders</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Reports</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Settings</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Status</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Add-ons</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">Qickview</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title">PHP Settings</h3>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

As you can it just shows some empty boxes. And each box has two buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
```

So users can expand and collapse boxes via minus button. Or delete them from the page via remove button.

Now all I want is to make these boxes already collapsed by default. I mean they should not be expanded as default.. For example look at this image below to understand what I mean:

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjhGB.png)

As you can see, users can choose which box they want to expand, and they are not shown by default...

So if you know the answer to this question, please let me know... thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the CSS class "collapsed-box" to the main box div, and substitute the "fa-minus" class with a "fa-plus" in the button text.

```
<div class="box box-solid">
    <div class="box-header">
        <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
        <h3 class="box-title">Orders</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        ....
    </div>
```

You can infer that by opening a page with a working box and widget, using the Chrome DevTools on the Elements tab, and inspect how the widget changes your HTML code.